# Why won't the shape move on the screen?

Tags: python, pygame

```py
import pygame 
pygame.init()

gameDisplay= pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("My game!")

gameEnd = False
gameDisplay.fill(white)
pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [400,300,10,10])
pygame.display.update()

lead_x = 300
lead_y = 300

while not gameEnd:

    for start in pygame.event.get():
        if start.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameEnd = True   
        if start.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if start.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x -= 10
            if start.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x += 10

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Can you describe a bit of your code context?

Answer (score 3):

You've to use the coordinates (`lead_x`, `lead_y`) in the call of `pygame.draw.rect`.
Clearing the display ([`.fill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill)), drawing the rectangle ([`pygame.draw.rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect)) and the update of the display ([`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update)) has to be done in the main loop. So the window is continuously redrawn and the rectangle is drawn at the current position in every frame:

```py
import pygame 
pygame.init()

gameDisplay= pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("My game!")

black   = (  0,  0,  0)
white   = (255,255,255)
lead_x  = 300
lead_y  = 300
gameEnd = False

while not gameEnd:

    for start in pygame.event.get():
        if start.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameEnd = True   
        if start.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if start.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x -= 10
            if start.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x += 10

    # clear window
    gameDisplay.fill(white)

    # draw rectangle at the current position (lead_x, lead_y)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [lead_x,lead_y,10,10])

    # update the display
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I then try to put what you put and the screen goes black.

Comment: Thank you Rabbid76, i noticed that i had to have spaces at the end, That why the screen was going black because i didn't know about the space at the end of the beginning of the words.